# how to open a port under Ipv4 instead of Ipv6

Tags: 14.04, networking, iptables, port-forwarding

How I can open a port under Ipv4 instead of Ipv6 on ubuntu

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*          LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*          LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*          LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:902             0.0.0.0:*          LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::1099                 :::*               LISTEN      7028/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:7778          :::*               LISTEN      7028/java
```

Or for example I want to change this line :

```
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:7778          :::*               LISTEN      7028/java
```

to

```
tcp       0      0 127.0.0.1:7778          :::*               LISTEN      7028/java
```

I already open that port using this command:

iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp –dport 7778 -j ACCEPT

Comment: What makes you think it is not open ?

Comment: I checked the open port using this command `netstat -tulpn`

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is ipv4 and the output shows several listening servers.

Comment: Normally you have to configure your server to listen on ipv4 / 6 so what server is listening on port 7778 ? you need to configure the server.

Comment: what do you mean by server? service? I use debian and Im running java program in it and I want that port (7778) open in Ipv4

Comment: Configure your java program to listen on ipv4 port 7778 .